# extracting before digits before and after forward slash /

Tags: r, regex, perl

I have trouble with extracting the string before and after `/`.

```
x <- c("maximusa/b=5/1","maximusa/b=-4/1","maximusa/b=3/-2")

before_slash=sub(".*=(\\d+).*","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

gives

```
"5"               "maximusa/b=-4/1" "3"
```

then

```
after_slash=sub("^.*\\/(d+)","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

gives

```
"maximusa/b=5/1"  "maximusa/b=-4/1" "maximusa/b=3/-2"
```

OTH, the expected output

before slash  5 -4  3

after slash   1  1 -2

how can I get the expected output ?

thx for answers,

I would like to add one more condition to extract the strings
assume we have string like that.
Same as the OP how could we extract with `+` sign as well as ignoring the parentheses ? Current solution of @mob gives

```
  x <- c("maximusa/b=(5/+1)","maximusa/b=(-4/1)","maximusa/b=(+3/-2)")

after_slash=sub("^.*/(\\d+)","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
> after_slash
[1] "maximusa/b=(5/+1)"  "1)"                 "maximusa/b=(+3/-2)"
```

and

```
 before_slash=sub(".*=(-?\\d+).*","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)

  > before_slash
[1] "maximusa/b=(5/+1)"  "maximusa/b=(-4/1)"  "maximusa/b=(+3/-2)"
```

I tried some but no luck!

Comment: @mob I edited the question title. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that

```
after_slash=sub("^.*\\/(d+)","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

should be

```
after_slash=sub("^.*/(\\d+)","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

To capture negative integers as well, you'll want to use

```
before_slash=sub(".*=(-?\\d+).*","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
after_slash=sub("^.*/(-?\\d+)","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

The tokens `-?` mean "the `-` character, 0 or 1 times"

Comment: what if I also have parantheses like this ? `x <- c("maximusa/b=(5/1)","maximusa/b=(-4/1)","maximusa/b=(3/-2)")`

Comment: I also forget to mention that I have also `+` sign before the digits.
`x <- c("maximusa/b=(5/+1)","maximusa/b=(-4/1)","maximusa/b=(+3/-2)")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all` to match a `-` (if any) followed by one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) and change the type of it to `numeric`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfc(str_extract_all(x, "-?[0-9]+"), as.numeric)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    V1    V2    V3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5    -4     3
#2     1     1    -2
```

---

Or with `read.table` after getting the substring with `sub` and then specifying the `sep` as `/` to create a two column data.frame

```
read.table(text= sub(".*=", "", x), sep="/")
#   V1 V2
#1  5  1
#2 -4  1
#3  3 -2
```

---

Or another option is `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "[=/]"), `[`, 3:4)
```

#### Update

If the OP's string have `()` as well, the first option should work well, but in the second option, we can change

```
x1 <- c("maximusa/b=(5/1)","maximusa/b=(-4/1)","maximusa/b=(3/-2)")
read.table(text= gsub(".*=|[()]", "", x1), sep="/")
#  V1 V2
#1  5  1
#2 -4  1
#3  3 -2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, too.

```
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(
  gsub("(^\\w*\\/)(b=)(-?\\d)(\\/)(-?\\d$)", "\\3 \\5", x), " "))), 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5   -4    3
# [2,]    1    1   -2
```